# I like carrots, but not bananas

Tags: riddle

First, a place in Germany,
Next, what some people think God is called,
Finally, a South African cricketer.

I’m like a herbivore,
But i don’t like apples.

What am I?

Comment: Is it _rabbit_ ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Also: encode your messages with rot13

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer might be

> [Wallaroo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallaroo)

First, a place in Germany,

> Perhaps the Berlin **Wall**

Next, what some people think God is called,

> **Alla**(h) - the arabic word for God

Finally, a South African cricketer.

> **Laroo** sounds like [Le Roux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garth_Le_Roux)

Comment: Good try, but not what I’m looking for